# Change the background color of a single chat bubble dynamically

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to dynamically change the chat bubble background. After doing a lot of researching I thought this was the correct approach but I it is not working for me. Can anyone clear this up for me?

At the top of my class I have:

```
var incomingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 104/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1.0))
    let outgoingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 63/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 1.0))
    var messages = [JSQMessage]()
```

I've also created an override where I think the bubble can be changed.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let data = messages[indexPath.row]

    switch(data.senderId) {
    case self.senderId:
        return self.outgoingBubble
    default:
        if(messageStatus == "Some Unique Value") {
          return JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 204/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1.0))
        } 
        return self.incomingBubble
      }
    }
```

Edit: Correcting the code to a workable place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that you are showing is the delegate implementation that is meant to let you change the bubble information based on each bubble, and it needs to have a corresponding object in the messages array.

You need to have all the message objects in one array and then as it places them on screen it will check to see who its from and respond with the appropriate bubble accordingly.  If the user is .senderId then its an outgoing bubble, etc...

This piece of this that you might be missing is that you need to declare what `self.outgoingBubble` and `self.incomingBubble` are.

At the top of your class you can declare these as constants.

```
 let outgoingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor(red: 0.07, green: 0.44, blue: 0.62, alpha: 1.0))
 let incomingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory().incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(UIColor(red: 0.87, green: 0.87, blue: 0.90, alpha: 1.0))
```

Or you can customize them inside the delegate method.

Comment: The outgoingBubble and the incomingBubble are the global settings and I was hoping to just change a single bubble in the delegate implementation. I thought this line would be able to change the bubble self.incomingBubble.messageBubbleImage.jsq_imageMaskedWithColor(UIColor(red: 119/255, green: 204/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1.0))

Comment: You need to return a separate one instead of modify the global one